# Is it possible to create an array using a const int parameter in a function in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to define an array inside my function, but the function does not know the size it needs to be. As C++ arrays can't be allocated from non-const variables, I passed the length it needs to be as a `const int`, but it gives me the error `expression must have const value`.

Why can I do

```
const int size = 5;
char word[size];
```

But not

```
const int size = 5;
someFunc(input, size);

...

someFunc(char * input, const int size) {
char word[size];
}
```

Even though my parameter is defined as `const int`, when I hover over the function call, it says it is just a regular int. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Just use `std::vector`

Comment: You can allocate array dynamically (perhaps using `std::vector`) or you can make this function into template accepting array size as a template parameter so it will be known at compile time.

Comment: You cans also make your array size `constexpr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C arrays must be declared with constant size known at compile time. In your first example, it is reasonably easy for the compiler to determine that the size of your array will be 5. However, in the second example, `someFunc()` could be called with any value so impossible for the compiler to know at compile time.

As others have said, you should prefer `std::vector<int>` which has the same interface but is more flexible and safer.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

---

The reason you can't use the `const int` parameter as the size of local c-style array is that you can think of two types of "const":

- known at compile time (enforced by `constexpr` sometimes)
- not known at compile time (and potentially changing e.g. between function calls with different arguments, even being `const`)

In this code:

```
const int size = 5;
char word[size];
```

`size` is known at compile time and compiler is smart enough to figure that out.

But when you use a function parameter names `size`, it's value is not known at compile time (and, in principle, you could call this function with different values of `size`, and all of them would still be `const` in the sense of "never changing at runtime").

Best general option for dynamic arrays is never using C-style arrays and using [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. If you know array size at compile time, use [std:array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Also see [P.6 in the C++ code guildelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#p6-what-cannot-be-checked-at-compile-time-should-be-checkable-at-run-time).